# WooCommerce - Import CSV of Products as Drafts

Tags: wordpress, csv, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Using the WooCommerce product importer im trying to import products as Drafts instead of Published. I want the ability to go in and fine-tune product details before they are live on website for customers to see.

Comment: Try the best free [WooCommerce product importer plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/)

Answer (score 0):

Create a column called Published and set values in each row as 0 under neath that column. Here is sample data https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/sample-data/sample_products.csv

Answer (score 0):

To be even more precise, according to the Woocommerce Product CSV Import Schema:

In the column named "Published" set the values as following;
1 for published, 0 for private, -1 for draft.

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Product-CSV-Import-Schema